# Beam for s'chach with wood glue + embedded screws

Tags: halacha, sukkah, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, schach, keilim-purity

Let's assume that there is a [*lechatchila*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323) to not use metal object that are *mekabel tumah* (susceptible to tumah) for something that supports the s'chach ("*maamid*"), which can be avoided by using something that supports something that supports s'chach ("*maamid d'maamid*"); but if it was used there is no issue [*b'dieved*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323) with using a *maamid* that is *mekabel tumah*. See [this article](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=2&ClipID=1509) by Rabbi Mansour for more information.

A friend of mine uses wooden beams to support his s'chach (which rest on his wooden walls). One of those beams fell and split. Buying or making a new beam proved to be too difficult, so he just put it back together, using Elmer's [wood glue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_glue) and screws.
As mentioned above, this would never be a problem *b'dieved*, but **might there be a problem *lechatchila* with**

1. **wood glue holding together the beam**
2. **metal screws holding together a beam**

**vis-à-vis using objects that are *mekabel tumah* as a *maamid*, or would we say that the metal elements in this beam are just *maamid d'maamid*?**

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2968/5323

Comment: +1 for [lemaaseh keilim shaylas](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25720/759) :)

Comment: @Scimonster Thanks :) ....btw I think [tag:sukkah] still applies

Comment: It's your question, you can tag it however you want. I thought the ikar of the question is about the schach, not really the succah.

Comment: @Scimonster All the same....it's still a question about the halachos of the sukkah.......http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18132263#18132263

Comment: @Scimonster Maybe hold off on edits, for now, till we settle this.

Comment: Isn't there a mishna in keilim about nails and broomsticks? On a related note, tags about different areas of taharos might be useful

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47466/5323

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20024&st=&pgnum=24