# Notched 2x4 for maamid?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, schach

Let's assume that there is a [*lechatchila*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323) to not use metal object that are *mekabel tumah* (susceptible to tumah) for something that supports the s'chach ("*maamid*"), which can be avoided by using something that supports something that supports s'chach ("*maamid d'maamid*"); but if it was used there is no issue [*b'dieved*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323) with using a *maamid* that is *mekabel tumah*. See [this Halachipedia article](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Materials_to_use_for_S%27chach#Schach_Held_Up_by_Unfit_Items) for more information.

What about a notched 2x4 board? Many people use long beams across their sukkos to support their schach -- are these *mekabel tumah*?

Here's a picture:

[image: 2x4s, each with a notch that removes a few inches along the length of the board from half of its cross-section]

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46211/5323

Comment: I may be missing the forest for the trees here - but what are the notches for? I don't believe I've ever seen those sold at home depot (although I could just be missing them). Were the notches put in for some sukkah related purpose or do they have a more general function?

Comment: @Bachrach44 They're there to hold them on to the sukkah walls.

Comment: The notch can't contain anything afaict.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is that the only thing that defines a כלי?

Comment: @Sho No, but not every כלי accepts Tumah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Also true.....part of the reason I asked was because I don't know the exact criteria for making something מקבל טומאה ;-)

Comment: @Shokhet Check out the [first Mishna in Keilim (ignoring the introductory chapter, which is well worth reading)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%90)

Comment: @DoubleAA *That* I knew already.....what I don't know is if this counts as פשוטי כלי עץ. Is a wooden knife מקבל טומאה? (no בית קיבול, but has a function.....?)

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47492/5323

Comment: `Let's assume that there is a lechatchila to not use metal object that are mekabel tumah (susceptible to tumah) for something that supports the s'chach` There are some who hold this, but it should be noted, that many hold that there is no problem at all, even l'chatchila.

Comment: @mevaqesh Yeah, I kind of wanted to avoid that discussion. I linked to an article in the question for more info on that.

Comment: @mevaqesh I think I understood that...let me check the link again, because I was pretty sure I saw that in there when I posted it...if you have a better link either let me know or go ahead and replace the one I have :)

Answer (score 1):

in shulchan aruch harav siman 628 sief 7 he writes regarding mats that are made for a few diffrent reasons that since they are not made for anything in particular therefore you go after the intention of the one buying it if his intentions are for a sukkah then they are not mikabel tumah

so to in this case the 2x4s are bought with the intentions of holding up the schach therefore they were never in the category of mikabel tumah

Comment: Mats do not have a beis kibul and so are not inherently a kli. A notch in wood is arguably different being that the notch is a beis kibbul, the lumber might no longer be called pshutei kli eits.

Comment: Those notches are made in order to hold up the sukkah nut for any other reason (I have never seen a price of wood with those notches in it except for a sukkah) so again they are sold as pshutei kli eitz and those notches are made solely for the sukkah and there is no time between four them to become a beis kibul litumah. See shailos utsuvos avnei neizer siman tof ayin gimmul and piskei tshuvos siman tof reish chof tes seif yud

Comment: @user6591 How is a notch a beis kibbul?

Comment: @user6591 - I second that. A notch is not a beth qibbul any more than the tip of an arrow that has been whittled down to a point; granted it is made to receive or interlock with another piece, but it is not a keli. Such arrows by the way are kosher sekhakh. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist I third it. I didn't say i think it is, I said it can arguably be said, meaning there is room for further clarification to ascertain if indeed the halakha for one applies to the other.

Comment: What if the notch was made as half of a half-lap joint? It is literally being made to be mekabel the other piece of wood. Does a beis kibul have to be something that holds liquid?

Comment: @user6591 Since a half pipe is not consider a kli kibul (though a U-bend might be a problem, since water pools in the bend) apparently notches would not transform a flat board into a kli kibbul. What might be a question is whether the notch becomes a chibbur between the two objects, since before they would potentially slide past one another and now they will not.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Trust me, there are winds every few years that prove the notch isn't a chibur. They slide sideways every year,  and if you tie mats to them, they go airborn every once in a while and land sideways. In a ruach she'eino metzuyah (eg Irwin even in its weakened, Tri-State Area, form) they will land off the deck altogether.