# Using Wooden Screws to Secure the Beams that Hold Up Schach?

Tags: sukkah, schach, maseches-keilim

Lechatchila one should not use metal objects that are mekabel tumah (susceptible to tumah) for something that supports the s'chach ("maamid"), however, "maamid d'maamid" is permissible. In line with this, there are those who use wooden beams to hold up the s'chach & carve out a notch on both ends (as seen in the image below) in order to secure the beams to the sukkah wall (see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47466/33583) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46211/beam-for-schach-with-wood-glue-embedded-screws) related question):

[image]

If one has a beam without a notch carved out, can one drill a hole on both ends of the beam and hold it in place using a **wooden** bolt and nut?

In this example, the beams are a few inches below the top of the sukkah (embedded inside the walls)

I can think of two reasons why it should be fine

**1**) wooden bolts and nuts are not M'ekabal Tumah (is this true?)

**2**) the wooden bolts and nuts are not directly holding up the s'chach they are simply ensuring that the beam which is holding up the s'cach doesn't shift. However, according to this reasoning (assuming it is true) the same could apply to metal screws (I think meta screws maybe problematic).

Would using wooden nuts and bolts to secure the beams be an issue?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: When it comes to wood, it must be able to contain something, in order to become impure, unlike metal, which can become impure regardless

Comment: That's a great idea. *Lichorah* it should be OK as per @שלום. The only practical problem you have is that if it rains on the screws they could expand and will become impossible to undo.

Comment: In addition to what has been mentioned wood it גידולי קרקע so should be okay