# Supporting schach on a sukkah

Tags: halacha, sukkah, schach, metals

I understand that it is preferable to support schach with materials that would themselves constitute schach.

I cannot find any information on whether it is permissible to use metal screws/nails to, for example, join two timber roof supports in the middle of the sukkah, under the schach. The schach would not be in contact with the metal screws, but it would be supported by timber which requires the screws to stay up.

Comment: Related (I think it's a duplicate, but it's unanswered): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46211/beam-for-schach-with-wood-glue-embedded-screws

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dave and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Hi Dave, even if it was placed on metal, it would be kosher bediavad. If it's a minute part of the schach, it's batel to the rov.

Comment: Hi Nisan, thanks, but I don't think that answers my question - I'm asking about what is permissible for the preferred supports for the schach.

Answer (score 1):

[Mishnah Brurah 629 s.k. 26:](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.629.26?lang=bi) says indirect support is not a problem:

> (כו) לחבר וכו' במסמרות של ברזל - זה מותר לכו"ע אפילו למאן דאוסר להעמיד הסכך בדבר המקבל טומאה כיון שאין סומך הסכך על המסמורים אלא שמחזיק בהם הכלונסות המעמידים להסכך

The majority of poskim agree that it is fine.

The Chazon Ish (O.C. 143:2) however holds that indirect support is the same as direct support and should therefore preferably not be used.